# How can i show time output only from ping command?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ping

I use the following command

```
ping -t 8.8.8.8
```

To get continuously output reply from 8.8.8.8 like this

```
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=53
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=53
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=53
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=53
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=53
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=53
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=53
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=53
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=53
```

My question is How can I do a special command in the run or in special code in bat file to give me the continuous output for time=xxms like this

```
time=7ms
time=3ms
time=7ms
time=4ms
time=7ms
time=5ms
time=7ms
time=2ms
time=7ms
```

Comment: change `-n 1` to `-n 2`

Comment: In this batch file `ping -t` displays nothing.

Comment: added second approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit.

Continuous output of ping latency.

Ctrl+C to break loop.

Script:

```
@rem Continuous output of ping latency.
@rem Windows 10 64-bit. 
@echo off 
@setlocal enableextensions
echo. 
echo Ctrl+C to break loop.
echo.
:59240034
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('ping -n 2 8.8.8.8 ^| findstr /i "time="') do echo %%a
goto :59240034
exit /b
```

OR:

```
@rem Continuous output of ping latency.
@rem Windows 10 64-bit. 
@echo off 
@setlocal enableextensions
echo. 
echo Ctrl+C to break loop.
echo.
:59240034b
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('ping -n 1 8.8.8.8 ^| findstr /i "time="') do echo %%a
sleep 1
goto :59240034b
exit /b
```

Results:

```
time=24ms
time=22ms
time=22ms
time=24ms
time=22ms
time=23ms
time=23ms
time=27ms
time=23ms
```

Comment: thank you. but I have a question why the numbers showing very fast not like normal ping -t output that shows the reply every second. what i am seeing now he showing the time very fast is here a way to execute it in every second?